# Breezejs stores all entities with Id:-1

Tags: javascript, odata, breeze

Here is the code:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'odata', true);
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('...');
manager.fetchMetadata().then(function() {
   var item = manager.createEntity('Todo', { Description: "Have fun",  CreatedAt: new Date(), IsDone: false});
   manager.saveChanges().then(function(data) {
      console.log('save ok:', data);
   }).fail(function(err) {
      console.log('save failed:', err);
   });
});
```

This code sends to server following record:

```
{"Id":"K_-1","Description":"Have fun","CreatedAt":"2014-06-03T18:16:11.982","IsDone":false}
```

I guess that could happen because my oData provider returns metadata not suitable for breeze:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
    <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="2.0">
        <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="TodoDatabase">
            <EntityType Name="Todo">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
                </Key>
                <Property xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" Name="Id" p6:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <Property MaxLength="200" Name="Description" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <Property Name="CreatedAt" Type="Edm.DateTime"/>
                <Property Name="IsDone" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityContainer m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" Name="Service">
                <EntitySet EntityType="TodoDatabase.Todo" Name="Todos"/>
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: In my point of view the Id is generated by the server side when an entity is posted to the server. So the client sends a '-1' is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breeze generates temporary IDs for store-generated keys ... which is what your metadata says you have. Your OData provider should have no problem receiving a temporary ID value such as -1. It should replace that with the permanent ID value and Breeze will make the adjustment on the client when it receives the inserted record.

Why are you concerned about the temp key value? Is the server objecting? If so how?

I cannot explain the "K_" prefix in `{"Id":"K_-1","Description": ...`; perhaps you can.

Comment: So this means that problem in backend, it should genreate `Id`, but it desn't, it just saves record to database as is, with `Id=-1`. But does `Breeze` genererates Id in some situations ?

Comment: Breeze is generating the -1 and sticking it in the Id property. The OData providers we usually work with ignore the incoming pk on an insert so this is harmless.  What OData provider are you using? Perhaps your OData provider sees that and says "Hmm. Looks like I should use the supplied Id (-1) rather than generate a new one". If so, you can teach Breeze not to send the Id for new records. Let's confirm first. What happens if you send the save with Fiddler/POSTMan w/o the Id in the payload?

Comment: BTW, we send the temp id for a good reason!  It is essential if the OData provider is capable of a $batch save that can reassemble a new entity graph (e.g., a new order and its new lineitems) from the separate entities in the batch. Again, that is typical of the OData providers we see (e.g. WCF Data Services backed by EF). Maybe yours inserts entity graphs differently.

Comment: But how can i teach breeze to not send `-1` in `Id` field ? I'm trying to setup this provider: http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-set-up-a-nodejs-odata-endpoint-with-odata-server

Comment: AHA! A JayData OData node provider eh. "OData" standard is like "Java" standard ... it's never standard in practice.  I don't have a clue how they implemented anything. But I'm happy to help smooth the bumps on a Breeze client. Give me a little time to put the answer together. Or ... you can use the Breeze/Node/Mongo npm module and get on with it; see the [Zza sample](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/node/zza-node-mongo) for how.